# Prolog program comprehension

Tags: prolog

This is the program I have:

```
foo(L,[H|R1]) :-
    foo(L,R1,H).

foo([H],[],H).
foo([H|T],[H|T1],R) :-
    foo(T,T1,R).
```

This is the query:

```
foo([1,2,3,4,5,6],X).
```

I don't understand what this program does, can someone help me and explain how does it work?

Comment: What do you think it does?

Comment: What result do you get when you do that query? Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog, there is no need to understand the source code. Instead, let Prolog do this for you. Just ask the **most general query**:

```
?- foo(L,R).
   L =    [_A],
   R =    [_A]
;  L =    [_A,_B],
   R = [_B,_A]
;  L =    [_A,_B,_C],
   R = [_C,_A,_B]
;  L =    [_A,_B,_C,_D],
   R = [_D,_A,_B,_C]
;  L =    [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],
   R = [_E,_A,_B,_C,_D]
;  L =    [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F],
   R = [_F,_A,_B,_C,_D,_E]
;  L =    [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G],
   R = [_G,_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F]
;  L =    [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H],
   R = [_H,_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G]
;  ... .
```

Do you see a pattern here?

Comment: in SWI Prolog, use `foo(L,R), numbervars(L).` ([SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/cAxIIUnk.pl)).

Comment: What does `L = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L],` mean? Is this an infinite term? :-)

Comment: well OK, let's call `foo(LL,RR), numbervars(LL).` instead.

Comment: SWI's toplevel is still a pain

Answer (score 2):

You could try to refactor it. If I start with:

```
foo(L, [H|R1]) :-
    foo(L, R1, H).

foo([H], [], H).
foo([H|T], [H|T1], R) :-
    foo(T, T1, R).
```

I can change the argument order foo(1,2,3) to foo(2,3,1):

```
foo(L,[H|R1]) :-
    foo(R1, H, L).

foo([], H, [H]).
foo([H|T1], R, [H|T]) :-
    foo(T1, R, T).
```

Now I can change the 2-nd argument of foo, and pass [H] instead of H:

```
foo(L, [H|R1]) :-
    foo(R1, [H], L).

foo([], H, H).
foo([H|T1], R, [H|T]) :-
    foo(T1, R, T).
```

Now you can rename the predicates to roll and append:

```
roll(L, [H|R1]) :-
    append(R1, [H], L).

append([], H, H).
append([H|T1], R, [H|T]) :-
    append(T1, R, T).
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand it easier, put the recursive clause above the base one:

```erlang
foo( [H | T], [H | T1], R) :- foo(          /* T = [_|_] */
          T,       T1,  R).
foo( [R],     [],       R).
```

So we advance along the two lists (that hold the same elements, `H`) until we hit the last element in the first list (`[R]`), at which point the second list is exhausted (`[]`), and we get hold of that last element (`R`).

This means that `foo( A, B, R) :- append( B, [R], A).`. Thus,

```erlang
foo( L, [E | R1]) :- % foo( L, R1, E).
                     append( R1, [E], L).    % R1 ++ [E] = L
```

i.e. `foo( L, M)` relates two lists `L`, `M`, where `L` is `M` with its first element `E` "flipped" to the list's end:

```erlang
 L :     .............E
 M :    E.............
 %       ---- R1 -----
```